# What the heck is going on? Chrome is giving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"

Tags: javascript, jquery

In chrome the following code is giving me an error on some pages, but not others...

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/package-assignments/add.json',
    method : 'POST',
    data : {
        event_id : ,
        package_id : $(this).data('package').id,
        price : $(this).data('package').price,
        deposit : $(this).data('package').deposit
    }
});
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what is going on. the area red underlined in chrome editor tools is "e-assignments/add.json'," which makes even less sense, it starts mid string on an arbitrary letter 'e' and continues to end of the string...

When I remove the string after url and replace it with null the error stays the same but shows to be after "$.ajax({" which also... makes no freaking sense...

Comment: Your event_id is missing: `event_id : ,`

Comment: Time for me to take a break... missing little stuff like this is when you know you've been at it for too long...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with: `event_id : ,` You aren't providing a value for `event_id` and the comma is encountered when it isn't expecting one.

Comment: That's provided via php, forgot to mention that. Nice catch, php was messing up

Comment: @MiDri include your PHP code which generates the JSON then, and we can take a look if you need.

Comment: But you don't have any inline PHP to inject it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - ya -- copied it from chrome's developer tools and not my source code. Been a long day... did not notice PHP was failing to include the event id. It's fixed now.

Comment: @MiDri Glad to hear it. Don't forget to mark this as the answer.